# Netbook 10' displays jelly bean forever

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

How do I start my new icraig net book, what can I do to start it up or do I have to return to the dealer. The battery is fully charged but i can't go beyond the first screen displaying jelly bean.

Comment: If it's never worked, then you should definitely consult the dealer first.

Comment: Tnx. It's never worked.

Comment: Have you tried doing a factory reset?